# PIN transfer between payment schemes

Tags: encryption, key, emv, payment

I am wondering, if it should be possible to transfer PIN in case of migrating between different payment schemes like Mastercard or VISA.

For example, when I have a card issued by Mastercard, and it will be changed to VISA, is it possible to keep the same PIN after issuing new card from VISA?

From my perspective, and what I was able to find, it should be possible, as the algorithm is based on PIN keys and offset in case of changing the PIN by user. If the algorihms are same in case of Mastercard and VISA, there should not be any issue.

Are there any specifics which should be considered to make PIN transfer happen?

Answer (score 2):

The PIN does not depend on the card number or to the type of card but is an independent property. In fact, many providers let you choose your own PIN and also let you change an existing PIN.